# react test, trying to remove a item from DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a test, in which if a button is clicked it should remove a item from the dom, I can successfully test if the button was clicked just once which should then trigger the delete sequence but it does not.

so i have a html tree like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>{props.label}<button onCLick={delete}>Remove</button></li>
  <li>{props.label}<button onCLick={delete}>Remove</button></li>
</ul>
```

in my test i am trying this:

```
 const testProps = {
    items: [
      {
        id: "0",
        label: "foo"
      },
      {
        id: "1",
        label: "bar"
      }
    ],
    onDelete: jest.fn()
}

      test("delete item", async () => {
        const { findAllByRole, queryByText } = render(<Items{...testProps} />);
    
        expect(queryByText("foo")).toBeInTheDocument();
    
        const deleteButton = await findAllByRole("button", {name: /remove/i})
        userEvent.click(deleteButton[0]);
    
    
        expect(testProps.onDelete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    
        await waitForElementToBeRemoved(
          expect(queryByText('')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
        );
      })
```

Also in the terminal i can see that the item is not actually getting deleted but the delete function is called, when i follow the same sequence in the UI the item i clock on to delete is just removed and gone from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the full code for your list component but judging from your test code, I think it is safe to assume your component doesn't have any sense of managing the state of the list of items you are passing to it. The component expects a function, but when tested in isolation (unit testing) it doesn't "know" what this function does, which is why you are passing a function mock.

I would say that on this level of testing (unit testing), all you really can check is that the items you passed to the component display as you expect, and that a function called "delete" was called the number of times you expect.

Presumably this component is used in another component where you actually manage the state of the items - testing that component would be considered an integration test where you test the implementation of your item list component and can expect items to be actually removed as you simulate clicks in your test.